# datepicker pop-up is not coming when url has child page

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

Datepicker is working if I use it on page "**localhost:4444/test**" , "**localhost:4444/test2**" and "**localhost:4444/dummy**" but if I change the URL to "**localhost:4444/test1/test2**" then it is **not** working. I have verified it on multiple times. If there is a child page then datepicker pop-up is not getting displayed.
I tried it even on a basic page without models.

Here I am using thymeleaf, webjars/bootstrap, webjars/jquery, webjars/bootstrap-datepicker.

I am new to frontend , let me know if I am missing anything here or for additional info.

**Edit1**: In all scenarios at least it is showing up, just problem with pop up

**Edit2**:
controller:

```
    @RequestMapping("/test")       [working]
public String testPage( ){
    return "helper/calender_test";
}

@RequestMapping("/test2/dummy")    [not-working]
public String dummyPage(){
    return "helper/calender_test";
}
```

helper/calender_test:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css}" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.standalone.css}" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.css}" type="text/css"/>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="input-group date" id='example'>
        <input class="form-control" type='text' placeholder= "date" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="input-group-text">
                  <i class='far fa-calendar-alt'></i>
              </span>
          </span>
    </div>


</div>
<script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js/}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script th:src="@{webjars/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $('#example').datepicker({

        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
        clearBtn: true,
        endDate: '0d',
        startDate: '-5y'

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Help us help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. I think there's a good chance your datepicker code is not being loaded into the sub-pages due to path issues. If you examine errors in your web console, you'll have more clues.

Comment: Yes. I can see some errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the root cause. There was one missing slash before the bootstrap-datepicker.js link. After giving the proper path it worked.